# How to show/hide divs based on values in localstorage?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need help with localStorage. I have 6 divs which include inputs and I have 6 checkboxes to turn these divs off and on. Here is my JS:

```js
    let formValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('formValues')) || {};
    let $checkboxes = $("#checkbox-container :checkbox");
    let $button = $("#checkbox-container button");
    function allChecked(){
        return $checkboxes.length === $checkboxes.filter(":checked").length;
    }
    function updateButtonStatus(){
         $button.text(allChecked()? "Uncheck all" : "Check all");
    }
    function handleButtonClick(){
    $checkboxes.prop("checked", allChecked()? false : true);
    }
    function updateStorage(){
        $checkboxes.each(function(){
        formValues[this.id] = this.checked;
    });
        formValues["buttonText"] = $button.text();
        localStorage.setItem("formValues", JSON.stringify(formValues));
    }
    $button.on("click", function() {
        handleButtonClick();
        updateButtonStatus();
        updateStorage();
    });
    $checkboxes.on("change", function(){
        updateButtonStatus();
        updateStorage();
    });
    $.each(formValues, function(key, value) {
       if (value == 'true') {
           $('#' + key + 'Input').css('display', 'block');
           $('#' + key).attr('checked', true);
    }  else {
           $('#' + key + 'Input').css('display', 'none');
           $('#' + key).attr('checked', false);
    }
       $('#' + key).click(function () {
          if (this.checked) {
              $('#' + key + 'Input').show();
          } else {
              $('#' + key + 'Input').hide();
          }
        });
    });
    // On page load
    $.each(formValues, function(key, value) {
         $("#" + key).prop('checked', value);
    });

    $button.text(formValues["buttonText"]);
```

This is my HTML for checkboxes:

```html
    <div class='container' id='checkboxes'>
        <h1></h1>
        <div class='container' id='checkbox-container'>
            <p></p>
            <h4></h4>
            <form action=''>
                <input type='checkbox' name='clientCode' id='clientCode' value='clientCodeInput'><label for='clientCode'>Client code</label><br>
                <input type='checkbox' name='InvAddr2' id='InvAddr2' value='InvAddr2Input'><label for='InvAddr2'>3rd address row</label><br>
                <input type='checkbox' name='exportFlag' id='exportFlag' value='exportFlagInput'><label for='exportFlag'>VAT zone</label><br>
                <input type='checkbox' name='countryCode' id='countryCode' value='countryCodeInput'><label for='countryCode'>Country code</label><br>
                <input type='checkbox' name='payDealCB' id='payDealCB' value='payDealCBInput'><label for='payDealCB'>Pay deal</label><br>
            <h4></h4>
                <input type='checkbox' name='articleCode' id='articleCode' value='articleCodeInput'><label for='articleCode'>Article code</label>
            </form>
            <button id='checkall'>Check all</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is HTML for inputs (example of one div):

```html
    <div class='form-group voluntary' id='clientCodeInput' style='display: none'>
        <label for='set_field.Code' class='col-form-label'>Code</label>
        <input type='text' name='set_field.Code' class='form-control'>
    </div>
```

Those 6 divs are not displayed by default, I used `display: none`. When you click on the checkbox, then it shows the div. At the moment the code saves if checkboxes are checked or not and after the refresh, it is still correct, but I am missing code for saving if div should be shown or not. This script I have put together based on what I have found here. I am a beginner, don't be harsh. Just point me in the right direction.
I tried to do something like this:

```
    $.each(formValues, function(key, value) {
      $("#" + key).prop('checked', value);
      if ($("#" + key).prop('checked', value) == 'true') {
          $('#' + key + 'Input').css('display', 'block');
      } else {
          $('#' + key + 'Input').css('display', 'none');
      }

    });
```

but this seems a bit stupid.

Edited:
This solves one of my problems:

```
Object.keys(formValues).forEach(function(key) {
  if (formValues[key] == true) {
      $('#' + key + 'Input').css('display', 'block');
  } else {
      $('#' + key + 'Input').css('display', 'none');
  }
});
```

**Edit**
Working code here:

```
let formValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('formValues')) || {};
let $checkboxes = $("#checkbox-container :checkbox");
let $button = $("#checkbox-container button");
function allChecked(){
    return $checkboxes.length === $checkboxes.filter(":checked").length;
}
function updateButtonStatus(){
    $button.text(allChecked()? "Uncheck all" : "Check all");
}
function handleButtonClick(){
    $checkboxes.prop("checked", allChecked()? false : true);
}
function updateStorage(){
    $checkboxes.each(function(){
        formValues[this.id] = this.checked;
    });
    formValues["buttonText"] = $button.text();
    localStorage.setItem("formValues", JSON.stringify(formValues));
}
$button.on("click", function() {
    handleButtonClick();
    updateButtonStatus();
    updateStorage();
    onOff();
});
$checkboxes.on("change", function(){
    updateButtonStatus();
    updateStorage();
});
$.each(formValues, function(key, value) {
    if (value == 'true') {
        $('#' + key + 'Input').css('display', 'block');
        $('#' + key).attr('checked', true);
    } else {
        $('#' + key + 'Input').css('display', 'none');
        $('#' + key).attr('checked', false);
    }
    $('#' + key).click(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            $('#' + key + 'Input').show();
        } else {
            $('#' + key + 'Input').hide();
        }
    });
});
// On page load
$.each(formValues, function(key, value) {
    $("#" + key).prop('checked', value);
});
$button.text(formValues["buttonText"]);
//localStorage-st loeme, kas checkbox märgitud või mitte
function onOff() {
    Object.keys(formValues).forEach(function(key) {
        if (formValues[key] == true) {
            $('#' + key + 'Input').css('display', 'block');
        } else {
            $('#' + key + 'Input').css('display', 'none');
        }
    });
}
onOff();
```

Comment: What is exactly happening? On page refresh your `div` is not displayed according to value of `localStorage` ?

Comment: with that if statement nothing happens actually, it only remembers which checkboxes are checked. But divs aren't shown.

Comment: something like this works: 
Object.keys(formValues).forEach(function(key) {
    if (formValues[key] == true) {
        $('#' + key + 'Input').css('display', 'block');
    } else {
        $('#' + key + 'Input').css('display', 'none');
    }
});

Comment: Now I need to figure out how to make check all and uncheck all to work